# Customizing TabMenu or TabView in PrimeNg in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, primeng

Description:

I'm currently working on a project where I need to recreate a widget like TabMenu/TabView in PrimeNg, but I'm having trouble having diffrent routerlinks on each button and customizing it to be like the image or just more dynamic.

**the widget that I want to create:**
[image]

Details:

Framework/Library: Angular, PrimeNg
Problem: I want to customize the **TabMenu/TabView from primeng**
What I want: I want it t take 90% of view width and for it to be centerd and the width of each tab to be like the image.
Current behavior: Describe what's currently happening when you apply your customization attempts.

HTML:

```
<div class="container "> 
   <p-tabMenu [model]="items"> 
</p-tabMenu> </div>
```

CSS: I tried many ways like trying to edit the container or editing these tags from prime ng [image]
but I just cant edit it

Comment: Customizing PrimeNG's TabMenu or TabView components to achieve a specific design may require a combination of Angular techniques and CSS custom styling

Comment: unfortunately I have tried many ways in CSS even overriding style elements that prime ng offers

Comment: Try to use the `::ng-deep .p-tabmenu {}` css selector

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that I hade it inside:

```
<div class="container "> </div>
```

the solutin is to remove the parent div:
HTML:

```
<p-tabMenu [model]="items" [activeItem]="activeItem"  (activeItemChange)="navigate($event)" >
```

CSS:

```
.p-tabmenu {
  border: none;
}
.p-tabmenu-nav {
  border: 1px white solid;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
.p-tabmenuitem {
  width: 50%;
}
.p-menuitem-link {
  width: 100%;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.p-menuitem-link:active ,.p-menuitem-link:focus{
  width: 100%;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 4px #127ae5 solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.p-menuitem-text {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #127ae5;
}
```

THE RESULT:
[image]